# Why does "[[1, 2], [3, 4]].indexOf([1, 2])" return -1?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, indexof

I spent the last hour and a half trying to find a bug in my code, when I finally realized that this JavaScript code:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]].indexOf([1, 2]);
```

returns `-1`, even though something such as `[1, 2, 3].indexOf(1);` correctly returns 0...

Why does this happen, and how can I find the correct index of the subarray?

Comment: Because `[1, 2] !== [1, 2]`.

Comment: Here you can find more ways to compare arrays: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `indexOf` takes only primitive arguments and you cannot match:

```
[1, 2] == [1, 2]
```

Which obviously gives `false`.

Comment: `indexOf` does a `===` instead of `==`. Now try to explain to the OP why `[42, NaN].indexOf(NaN)` returns `-1`. :D

Comment: @IonicăBizău Both `NaN == NaN` and `NaN === NaN` returns `false`. `NaN` is not a primitive type.

Comment: @IonicăBizău — "indexOf does a === instead of ==" — That doesn't make a difference here.

Comment: @Quentin You're right, but the OP can say: Why does `["42"].indexOf(42)` return `-1`? That's my point. It should be `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: When `==` itself gives a `false`, `===` we can be very sure, it gives `false`.

Comment: @IonicăBizău I am not telling that `indexOf` does a `==`. I am just telling that `NaN == NaN` gives a false. `#Difference`

Comment: "_The indexOf takes only primitive arguments_" Nope, you can check a reference with `indexOf` too.

Comment: @Teemu Lemme check.

Comment: @PraveenKumar *The indexOf takes only primitive arguments* — `a = [1, 2]; [a, [1, 2]].indexOf(a) // => 0`

Comment: @Teemu From MDN: `searchValue`
*A string representing the value to search for.* AFAIK, `string` is a primitive data type... `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Exactly. Is it primitive?

Comment: Hmm... Your last comment wasn't probably pointed to me? [Here you can see](https://jsfiddle.net/gqs7ndtp/) an object found by `indexOf` method.

Comment: @IonicăBizău According to MDN, yes, but according to reality, no.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Reference? MDN says: *In JavaScript, there are 6 primitive data types: string, number, boolean, null, undefined, symbol (new in ECMAScript 2015).* Where would you put my `a`?

Comment: @PraveenKumar String.prototype.indexOf != Array.prototype.indexOf

Comment: You can certainly pass any value to `Array#indexOf`, not just primitive values.

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate the array and check every item of the pattern and return the index.

```js
function getIndexOf(array, pattern) {
    var index = -1;
    array.some(function (a, i) {
        if (a.length !== pattern.length) {
            return false;
        }
        if (a.every(function (b, j) { return b === pattern[j]; })) {
            index = i;
            return true;
        }
    });
    return index;
}

console.log(getIndexOf([[1, 2], [3, 4], [7, 8]], [7, 8]));
```

Another way with JSON and `indexOf`.

```js
function getIndexOf(array, pattern) {
    return array.map(function (a) { return JSON.stringify(a); }).indexOf(JSON.stringify(pattern));
}

console.log(getIndexOf([[1, 2], [3, 4], [7, 8]], [7, 8]));
```

Comment: or one can use **a.join("")** instead of  **JSON.stringify(a)**